# Curl Command Equivalent in Python (requests)

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests

What could be the Python equivalent code (requests library) to the following CURL command?

```
curl -i -x POST -H "content-type: multipart/form-data" -F file = abc.txt http://localhost:xxxx/ -F 'params= { "key1": "val1", "key2": "val2" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use requests library
you need to install requests library and after that

```
import requests
params = { 'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
files = {'file': open('abc.txt', 'rb')}
r = requests.post('your_link', params=params, headers=headers, files=files)
```

For more information you can use https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: I understand that but there are two -F options in the curl command. I am wondering how to make use of files through requests library